# Android - Populating ArrayList objects in custom layout view

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I'v a difficulty understand how this should work. I have a method `getAllNotes()` that returns **ArrayList** in my **DatabaseHandler Class** which is working fine when I try to loop through the **ArrayList** like this:-

```
    for (Note note : notes) {
        String log = "Id: " + note.getID() + " ,Title: " + note.getTitle() + " ,Description: " + note.getDescription();
        Log.d("Notes: ", log);
    }
```

This is how the method looks like

**DatabaseHandler.java**
[image]

Now I need to populate these data into a listview. After some search work, I find out that I need to use **ArrayAdapter** and a **Custom Layout** with textview for each object in the array (ID, Title, Description).

I couldn't fully understand how **ArrayAdapter** should work.

**MainActivity.java**
[image]

1- Why do I need to define **setAdapter** to **listview** and I already have my **custom listview** ?

2- **ArrayAdapter** requires the resource ID to be a **TextView**, and I have multiple textviews in my custom listview layout !!

3- The results looks very strange, I supposed that I will have a simple list with only titles but this is what I got.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create own adapter class.

Change your modeClass in ArraList
Change your layout in getView()

Fast Example:

```
private ArrayList<MenuModel> menuModels;
private Context context;

public MenuAdapter(ArrayList<MenuModel> menuModels, Context context) {
    this.menuModels = menuModels;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return menuModels.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return menuModels.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MenuModel menuModel = menuModels.get(position);
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_menu, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.textView.setText(menuModel.getTitle());
    viewHolder.image.setImageResource(menuModel.getResourceIcon());

    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;
    TextView textView;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.);
        textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menuTitle);
    }
}
```

}